# Timeline of the battle of the ten kings in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

What is the timeline of the battle of the 10 kings mentioned in the Vedas? What are the circumstances that lead to the battle and also, what is the best account(translated) of the events surrounding the battle?

Comment: The book http://www.amazon.in/Ten-Kings-Ashok-Banker/dp/938150654X?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=3882a5f8-dd76-4e53-8bdc-867606f0cd7f gives an interesting account of the story. This book is 'inspired' from the RgVeda.

Comment: Quite literally the only source of information we have for this battle are allusions to it in the hymns of Vasishta in Book 7 of the Rig Veda.