# Is there a scriptural base, from other than the Veda and Puranas, to indicate that the Battle of the Ten Kings occurred?

Tags: rig-veda, upanishads, brahmanas

**There is already a question existing - [Timeline of the battle of the ten kings in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13747/3869).  However, there are no answers posted yet and my question is different.**

---

It was mentioned in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) that The **Battle of the Ten Kings** (Sanskrit: दाशराज्ञ युद्ध, romanized: Dāśarājñá yuddhá) is a battle alluded to in the Rigveda (Book 7, hymns 18, 33 and 83.4–8), the ancient Indian sacred collection of Vedic Sanskrit hymns.

It was also mentioned that the battle took place during the middle or main Rigvedic period, near the Ravi River in Punjab. It was a battle between the Puru Vedic Aryan tribal kingdoms of the Bharatas, allied with other tribes of the north west India, and the Trtsu-Bharata (Puru) king Sudas, who defeats other Vedic tribes.

---

However, mention of the **Battle of the Ten Kings** is missing in  [Bṛhaddevatā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%B9%9Bhaddevat%C4%81), but many a translator of Rig Veda, including Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton, mentioned it as occurred.

Was it mentioned in brAhmanas or aranyakas or upanishads or any commentary on Rig Veda/any **other literary work**, other than Puranas, by Indian authors of past era(prior to 18th centuary) that the **Battle of the Ten Kings** (दाशराज्ञ युद्ध) really occurred ?

If so, please provide references.